# How to get a name of file that that my link reffers to?

Tags: c, linux, stat

i have a problem with my code, i dont exactly know how to get a name of file that my link reffers to, thats my code:

And for example:
my output:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 damiankus studinfo 4 10-15 23:49 pliksoft

i want:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 damiankus studinfo 4 10-15 23:49 pliksoft -> plik

and i dont exactly know how to get the name of the file my link reffers to.

Comment: Use readlink() system call. Read the manual as readlink() does not put a terminating nul char. So, put explicitly 0 in the buffer before the call.

Comment: Check existing code of e.g. `ls`.

Comment: @RachidK. The nul char should be set _after_ the `readlink` call. (e.g.) `ssize_t len = readlink(path,buf,sizeof(buf) - 1); if (len >= 0) buf[len] = 0;`

Comment: @CraigEstey: Yes you right. But it is also possible to set the entire buffer to 0 (e.g. with a memset()) prior to the system call. And supposing that the buffer is big enough, the resulting string will be NUL terminated ;-) But I agree with the fact that your method is more optimal.

Comment: @RachidK. Yes, a preset with `memset` is an alternative. I think the most important part is to use `sizeof(buf) - 1` to _guarantee_ space for the nul. (e.g.) If 1024 were the maximum permissible length, I'd do: `char buf[1024 + 1];` and pass 1024 to `readlink`

Comment: Thanks guys a lot, it works perfectly as intended much love <3

Answer (score 0):

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and also [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)

You want to use [readlink(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html)

Use also both [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand the dynamic behavior of programs.

So using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compile your code [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) (and [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/))